# cannot install rgdal package

Tags: r, package, rgdal

I tried to install rgdal by building from sources but it returns an error:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: you need to first install gdal on your pc and then install the rgdal package

Comment: One way of installing GDAL on your Mac is via Homebrew (http://brew.sh). First install Homebrew, then `brew install gdal` in a Terminal to install GDAL.

Comment: I second the use of `homebrew` but there's also a pretty [comprehensive explanation](http://tlocoh.r-forge.r-project.org/mac_rgeos_rgdal.html) of how to do this on OS X (not requiring `homebrew` and offering 3 alternative ways).

Comment: Thanks @maRtin, WhiteViking and hrbrmstr! My problem's been solved!!! Thank you so much!!!